# Compatibility issues of tensorflow with numpy versions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow via my Anaconda prompt and the command

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Thus, tensorflow-2.12.0 was installed. However, this came with the error message

> numba 0.55.1 requires numpy<1.22,>=1.18, but you have numpy 1.22.4 which is incompatible.

When I downgrade my numpy to a version I believe to be compatible with numba with

```
pip install numpy==1.21.6
```

I now get the error message

> tensorflow-intel 2.12.0 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.21.6 which is incompatible.

Am I mistaken or is this rather contradictory? How should I proceed here? I intend to start learning about Machine Learning algorithms so I am uncertain how much numba I will need there.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of `numba`?

Comment: Try creating a new environment and start by installing Tensorflow before anything else. It should install all its dependencies automatically without conflicts.

Comment: thanks, I went with the creating a completely new environment and after installing each required package manually, it works now

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, try to install the 1.18 version of numpy,

```
pip install numpy==1.18
```

Keep me updated if it works !

Comment: Quote : `tensorflow-intel 2.12.0 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.22`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35527810)